# Equation (line) in tikzpicture not completely visible

Tags: pgfplots

I have this code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xlabel = x, 
            xmin = 0, 
            xmax = 20, 
            ylabel = y, 
            ymax = 0.8, 
            ymin = 0, 
            ytick pos=left
]
\addplot [black] {-0.01 * x + 0.6};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

I get this result:

[image]

Why is it only showing the line for x between 0 and 5?

I would like to have the line for x as defined in the axis.

Comment: `domain=0:20`. The default domain is `-5:5`.

Comment: Thanks, that works!